# What is the differnce between decimal? and decimal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I know this is a silly question.I'm trying to studying ASP.Net MVC 4 myself and recently I'm encountered with a doubt The tutorial I'm using to study MVC shows an MVC Model creation contain the following code

```
public decimal? cost{get;set;}
```

and I'm wondering why they put ? in the code The tutorial didn't explain why they put that ? in the code. So my question is what is the difference between decimal and decimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`decimal?` can have `null` value

while `decimal` cannot have `null` value, it must always have value

more about nullable types on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx

look at the following example

```
decimal? foo = null; // value is null
foo = 5.5M;  // value is 5.5
foo = null; // value is null again
```

you cant have this behavior with not nullable type

```
decimal foo = null; // produces compiler error, Cannot convert null to 'decimal'
```

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2005, we're introducing a new type named "Nullable", that looks something like this (it's actually more complex than this, but I want to keep the example simple):

```
struct Nullable<T>
{
    public bool HasValue;
    public T Value;
}
```

You can use this struct directly, but we've also added some shortcut syntax to make the resulting code much cleaner. The first is the introduction of a new syntax for declaring a nullable type. Rather than typing:

```
Nullable<int> x = new Nullable<int>(125); I can write:

int? x = 125;
```

You can read this in detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/05/27/143221.aspx)

Comment: You should probably write a description yourself instead of copying it from the link. I was a bit confused for a second when I read that something new was being introduced in an 8 year old version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

decimal? ist nullable, that means, it can have no value at all (null not 0). You can e.g. pass this to your client and show a text "no data" instead of "0".

Answer (score 0):

decimal is a value type. Adding the question mark makes it Nullable.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28VS.80%29.aspx